# Correlation Coefficient - $\rho(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If I have two aleatory variables
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\ \frac{1}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{6}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$Y=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\ \frac{1}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{6}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\end{pmatrix}$$ how can I calculate $$\rho(X,Y) \mbox{?}$$

$\rho$ -correlation coefficeint.

thanks:)

Comment: What does your notation mean?  If the $1/36$'s are supposed to be probabilities, they don't add up to $1$.  If they are supposed to be the values of the random variables, then both $X$ and $Y$ are constants, and correlation coefficient is undefined for a constant.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I have corrected. You are right. Can you help me, please :)

Comment: What is "the ρ-correlation coefficient"? The correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find the correlation without additional information.  $X$ and $Y$ could be independent, in which case the correlation is $0$, or (in this instance) $X$ might always be equal to $Y$ so the correlation would be $1$, or $X$ might (again, in *this* instance) be equal to $14-Y$ (as $X$ goes from $2$ to $12$, then $14-X$ goes from $12$ to $2$), in which case the correlation is $-1$, or they could be related in more complicated ways, in which case the correlation could have any <s>of a large (but in this case finite) number of possible other</s> value<s>s</s> between $1$ and $-1$.

<s>Since the number of possible values of the correlation is in this case finite, one could say that there's enough information given to deduce at least something about the correlation.</s>

Comment: Re "a large (but in this case finite) number of possible other values between 1 and −1", why *finite*? Any number in [-1,1] can be realized.

Comment: @Did : OK, by hindsight I was thinking of listing $36$ possible outomes, one of which results in $X=2$, two of which result in $X=3$, and so on, and then looking at all permutations of a similar set of $36$ outcomes corresponding to $Y$, letting each correspond to one of the $36$ outcomes giving rise to the $X$ values, according to the particular permutation that was chosen.  However, now that you mention it, one can subdivide any one of those $36$ $Y$-outcomes and let one part correspond to one $X$-outcome and another to another, and split those pieces up to be as small as you want.  Hence...

Comment: ....Hence I conclude that you are right.

Comment: To get correlation $-1\leqslant c\leqslant1$, choose $Y=14U+(1-2U)X$ where $U$ is independent of $X$ and Bernoulli with $P[U=1]=\frac12(1-c)$ and $P[U=0]=\frac12(1+c)$.